# issue running Jekyll on Windows localhost

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, jekyll

To start, I'm new to Ruby and using localhost.

I'm using: Windows 8 Pro, Ruby is installed to `C:\Ruby200`, Ruby Devkit is installed to `C:\RubyDEV`, `config.yml` is properly configured to the correct directories, as well.

gem specs seem to be stored in `C:\username\.gem`

And finally, the `Jekyll gem` installed perfectly according to command prompt. The correct `PATH` to bin is also set.

`jekyll --server` being run said to go to 'localhost:4000', but didn't seem to set up perfectly. It originally gave me a Forbidden error when trying to access `/`, but now it doesn't seem to want to load at all.

I've consulted a few tutorials.

- http://www.testically.org/2012/02/02/installing-jekyll-and-ruby-on-windows/
- http://zolomon.com/tutorial/2012/02/23/setting-up-jekyll-on-windows-7/
- http://mahoney.eu/2011/12/12/installing-jekyll-on-windows/#.UVfxGle_Owg
- http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2011/09/01/runningjekyllwindows.html

I didn't install any extra dependencies, which seem to be optional according to what I'm hearing, to replace Textile and such.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Newest error after switching to 1.9.3

```
C:\RubyDEV>jekyll --server
WARNING: Could not read configuration. Using defaults (and options).
        No such file or directory - C:/RubyDEV/_config.yml
Building site: C:/RubyDEV -> C:/RubyDEV/_site
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371:in `initialize': Permission denied -
 C:/RubyDEV/_site/bin/bashbug (Errno::EACCES)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371:in `block in copy_file'

        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1370:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1370:in `copy_file'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:477:in `copy_file'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:396:in `block in cp'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1515:in `block in fu_each_sr
c_dest'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1531:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1513:in `fu_each_src_dest'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:395:in `cp'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/static
_file.rb:58:in `write'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/site.r
b:256:in `block in write'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/site.r
b:255:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/site.r
b:255:in `write'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/site.r
b:43:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/bin/jekyll:264:in
 `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'

C:\RubyDEV>
```

Comment: Are you running your console as administrator? (right click - run as administrator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lot of gems aren't prepared yet for Ruby 2.0, specially since Windows requires pre-compiled binaries.

This is mentioned in the [RubyInstaller 2.0.0-p0 announcement](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rubyinstaller/mg5ailNICvM/discussion) at RubyInstaller list, going to reproduce it here just for completeness of the answer:

> - Existing pre-compiled gems are not Ruby 2.0 compatible
>
> Ruby 2.0 introduces ABI breakage which means compiled C extensions
>   with previous 1.9.3 will work with Ruby 2.0.
>
> DO NOT install Ruby 2.0 on top of existing Ruby 1.9.3, or try to use
>   compiled  extensions with it.
>
> You will be required to force compilation of those gems:
>
> ```
> gem install <name> --platform=ruby
> ```
>
> This will require you have the extra dependencies required for that
>   gem to  compile. Look at the gem documentation for the requirements.

To work around your current situation, you will need to uninstall `yajl-ruby` and force installation:

```
gem install yajl-ruby --platform=ruby
```

Considering are other gems like RDiscount that doesn't work properly on this release (yet), perhaps will be better if you use Ruby 1.9.3 instead.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I got a little farther this time, but it still returned some errors. I edited the question to show them.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar installation : Win7 / Ruby 2.0. The Jekyll server run well, but : I'd installed the latest Jekyll version (from github : gem isn't yet released), same thing for rdiscount (see the issues : https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount/issues/91, the new gem 2.0.7.2 for ruby 2.0 will be released next days).

I've still got some issues if I want another markdown library (maruku, kramdown ...), had to stay for the moment with rdiscount.
Have you check you've got the good file `_config.yml` and not just `config.yml` ?

... Seems that you launch your jekyll site in the same directory that your DevKit install ?? For testing purpose, just create a new directory,(ie c:\www\my_site), download a sample Jekyll site from github (ie https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap/archive/master.zip and unzip in the directory, the run jekyll in that directory (where is _config.yml).